# How to embed an angular element inside an angular application?

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I have an angular element, goes with custom tagname - `fancy-button`. How can I embed `fancy-button` in a angular application?

I have tried the following ways, but none of them worked -

1. Imported angular-element script in `index.html/angular.json[scripts]` and embedded `fancy-button` in `app.component.html` (root component running in angular application)
2. Imported angular-element script in `app.component.html` and also embedded `fancy-button` in `app.component.html` (root component running in angular application)

Thanks

Comment: How about putting the angular-element script in `scripts` in `angular.json`?

Comment: @ChauTran I tried include in scripts but it doesn`t work. I think i am missing something.

Comment: @MoazzamKhanany have you come to any solution?

Comment: @PavanShukla yes, but it was a bit complicated. I will try to post it here in couple of days.

Comment: @MoazzamKhan Hi, we're facing the same issue. Can you post your solution please?

Answer (score 1):

To `index.html`, I added:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/cappapproot.js"></script>
```

(`cappapproot.js` is the name of my Angular Element js)

This caused an `Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded.` To resolve this error, in `pollyfills.ts` I commented out the line:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

Comment: it worked for me too, when placed within index.html, but it does not work for any other component (eg, app.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

in the end, I managed to implement the custom element in my application. You should do the next steps:

1. In your `angular.json` add the script file in your selected project:

```
    ...,
    "projects": {
        "my-awesome-project": {
        ...,
        "architect": {
            "build": {
                "options":{
                    ...,
                    "scripts": [
                        ...,
                        "[path to your awesome Element js]/[awesome-element].js"
                    ],
                    ...
                 },
             ...
         },
         ...
     }
```

2. In your `polyfills` files include `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.` at the end of the file.
3. In the `module` you want to include your `Angular element` you must add the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` in the `schemas` parameter of the `decorator`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure your using the correct element name? Can you post your component + usage?